# Gridlayout button click then load under the buttons a form Java

Tags: java, swing, bluej

I really didn't now how to form the question i have a gridlayout with 4 buttons. When the user press Add module i want under the buttons a form instead of a new windows if this is possible.

```
frame = new JFrame("ModuleViewer");
   makeMenu(frame);

   Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();

    // Specify the layout manager with nice spacing
   contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));

   addModule = new JButton("Toevoegen Module");
   contentPane.add(addModule);

   overview = new JButton("Overzicht Modules");
   contentPane.add(overview);

   addSchoolweeks = new JButton("Aapassen schoolweken");
   contentPane.add(addSchoolweeks);

   weekheavy = new JButton("Weekbelasting");
   contentPane.add(weekheavy);

   frame.pack();

   Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
   frame.setLocation(d.width/2 - frame.getWidth()/2, d.height/2 - frame.getHeight()/2);
   frame.setVisible(true);
```

I know that i first need to add een action method for the buttons i know how to do that so that isn't important. I only want to know how i could create a layout under the buttons so when a user clicks the layout will be draw.

Comment: Have a look at the [CardLayout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: can i combine the cardlayout tutorial with the gridview tutorial?

Comment: See my answer below about using multiple layouts.

Answer (score 3):

Each panel can only have one layout, but you can use multiple panels for the desired effect: a top panel using GridLayout to hold your buttons, and a bottom panel using CardLayout to hold multiple other panels, one for each button click.  Each of these panels can use whatever layout you want, depending on its contents.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CardLayoutDemo implements Runnable
{
  final static String CARD1 = "Red";
  final static String CARD2 = "Green";
  final static String CARD3 = "Blue";

  JPanel cards;
  CardLayout cardLayout;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new CardLayoutDemo());
  }

  public void run()
  {
    JButton btnRed   = createButton("Red");
    JButton btnGreen = createButton("Green");
    JButton btnBlue  = createButton("Blue");

    JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,3));
    buttons.add(btnRed);
    buttons.add(btnGreen);
    buttons.add(btnBlue);

    JPanel card1 = new JPanel();
    card1.setBackground(Color.RED);

    JPanel card2 = new JPanel();
    card2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    JPanel card3 = new JPanel();
    card3.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    cards = new JPanel(cardLayout);
    cards.add(card1, CARD1);
    cards.add(card2, CARD2);
    cards.add(card3, CARD3);

    JFrame f = new JFrame("CardLayout Demo");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(buttons, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    f.add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.setSize(300, 200);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }

  private JButton createButton(final String name)
  {
    JButton button = new JButton(name);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
        cardLayout.show(cards, name);
      }
    });

    return button;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how that actionPerformed works. I know it is invokes when i click on a button. but how can i make for each button the action normally i do this  class nieuwListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            moduleNaamLabel = new JLabel("Naam Module: ");
            addModule.add(moduleNaamLabel);
            System.out.println("Help");
        }
    }